# box.net OAuth2 authorization without browser

Tags: perl, curl, oauth-2.0

For box.net is it possible to get the OAuth2 Authorization Code without using the browser?

I am trying to use perl and have managed to get to the grant access page. This is the page where user presses the grant access button in the browser.

Sending post via perl in earlier stages works fine, but it does not work simulating the grant accrss button  and returns
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close

with message "Your Box account may be temporarily unavailable. We're working on resolving the issue and should be back up soon."

i got the same response when i used curl. If i try it with the browser it works fine by returning the authorization code in the url part of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, the purpose of that page is for the owner of the Box resources to consent to giving your app access. If he's not logged in, he will have to enter credentials and then consent. You see the consent page, because you are likely to be authenticated already; but the general use is that your app is requesting a user access ti his data in box.

Comment: i know about the consent, i was using my test account...i was able to bypass the user login page via a http post request using perl and finally get to the accept page. i tried to do that same technique with the accept button but it does not seem to work. i am sure that the post name-values passed are correct as i used fiddler to inspect the actual values passed from the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved my problem....turned out i was missing some parameters, so i used fiddler and found out the post/get parameters that where needed and i recreated the requests using libcurl. And in doing so i was able to bypass the browser.